# ';' expected when trying to map to array of objects

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to map to a object in vue but I get

';' expected when trying to map to a object

on the colon between 'key' and 'd.id' and between 'value' and d.date().

```
const documentData = snapshot.docs.map(d => {'key':d.id,'value':d.data()});
```

But this

```
const testObject = {'key':'1', 'value':'2'};
```

works fine.

Comment: `=> {` is not an expression but a block - wrap it `=> ({...})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const documentData = snapshot.docs.map(d => {'key':d.id,'value':d.data()});
```

The problem with this snippet of code is that in a lambda expression, `{}` is interpreted as a block of statements rather than an object. In order to fix this, simply surround the object notation with parenthesis like so

```
const documentData = snapshot.docs.map(d => ({'key':d.id,'value':d.data()}));
```